# How to measure time of Algorithm

Tags: java, time

I have an algorithm and I want to measure the time it works, but I get 0.
How to fix it? start and end are the same.

```
public static String MD5(String message) {
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.update(message.getBytes());
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.digest();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((hashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                    .substring(1));
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MD5TIME = end - start;
        System.out.println(end);
        System.out.println(start);
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT

But now unfortunately when I write statics: MD5 and SHA-1 into the file, they still are 1 and 2.

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class ShortCuts {
volatile static long  MD5TIME = 1, SHA1TIME = 2;
    public static String MD5(String message) {
        try {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md5.update(message.getBytes());
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.digest();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((hashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                        .substring(1));
            }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            MD5TIME = end - start;
            System.out.println(MD5TIME);
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String SHA(String message) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] t = SHA1.prepareDataForSHA1(message);
        SHA1TIME = System.nanoTime() - start;
        return SHA1.doSHA1(t);
    }

    public static void addShortcutsIntoTheFile(BufferedWriter bw, String message) {
        try {
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("MD5");
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println(MD5TIME);
            bw.write("TIME: " + MD5TIME);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(ShortCuts.MD5(message));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("SHA");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("TIME: " + SHA1TIME);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write(ShortCuts.SHA(message));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
    MD5
TIME: 1
c4909803cf840c8cf0556e16e4cc1483

SHA

TIME: 2
7d3f446eef84b651dc7b519fe5ad4157279cb45e
```

CONSOLE

```
794076
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) for more precise measurement

**Note:**

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time

---

**See Also**

- [How to find time taken to run java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646467/how-to-find-time-taken-to-run-java-program)

Comment: What does `System.out.println(MD5TIME);` outputs ?

Comment: unfortunately 1 the staics value has not been modificated, checked it sec ago

Comment: For SHA you are still using System.currentTimeInMillis() , and try cleaning and compiling code again

Comment: I corrected it. The method addshorcuts... is called from the other class the original static valuse are not modificated. I will edit fast.

Comment: Could you please try scaling the computation little more may be by doing the calculation 1000 times, or post the exact code to reproduce IDEone may be

Answer (score 3):

Or better, use a tool designed for micro-benchmark: [Google's Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/)

[How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/4480774#4480774)

Comment: Can the gentleman who down voted care to explain the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the resolution of your timer. But if you're getting numbers (in millis) of zero, then you may get a more accurate answer by timing multiple executions of the functionality (1000+) in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code, works fine:

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class ShortCuts {
volatile static long  MD5TIME = 1, SHA1TIME = 2;
    public static String MD5(String message,BufferedWriter bw) {
        try {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md5.update(message.getBytes());
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.digest();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((hashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                        .substring(1));
            }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            MD5TIME = end - start;
            System.out.println(MD5TIME);
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println(MD5TIME);
            bw.write("TIME: " + MD5TIME);
            bw.newLine();
            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String SHA(String message, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] t = SHA1.prepareDataForSHA1(message);
        SHA1TIME = System.nanoTime() - start;
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("TIME: " + SHA1TIME);
        bw.newLine();
        return SHA1.doSHA1(t);
    }

    public static void addShortcutsIntoTheFile(BufferedWriter bw, String message) {
        try {
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("MD5");

            bw.write(ShortCuts.MD5(message,bw));
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("SHA");
            bw.write(ShortCuts.SHA(message,bw));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Though the accepted answer to your question provides simple answer, it is unfortunately not the correct approach for determining the proper time.