# Counting down or Counting up, Which one is faster?

Tags: java, performance, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which of these pieces of code is faster in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656506/which-of-these-pieces-of-code-is-faster-in-java)

If i write a loop as

```
for (int i=n; i>=0; i--)
```

And other one as

```
for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
```

In java which one would be faster and why?..Say **n=10000**

Comment: Run it and time it yourself. I recall seeing something about decrements being slower than increments, albeit, by small amounts of time. 10 ms or so.

Comment: in terms of performance they are both the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646467/how-to-find-time-taken-to-run-java-program

Comment: Neither. They are the same. Each requires the same work of the ALU.

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra.. `=<` is not the same as `<=`. First one will not compile.

Comment: Unless the performances of `++` and `--` are different, there's no actual difference. Even if there was, you'll need an extense loop to actually get to notice it in a way that can harm your application's overall performance.

Comment: @Max What do you mean, "10 ms or so"? We're talking nanoseconds here.

Comment: @Max But in my case its decrement which is faster.Why is it so?

Comment: This is more than adequately explored here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656506/which-of-these-pieces-of-code-is-faster-in-java

Comment: This has been asked before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181941/loop-counter-in-java-api

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry, I should clarify. I'm pretty sure what I read was a loop with thousands of elements. Thus the delay between the two was in ms.

Comment: @Max Thousands of elements turns nanoseconds into microseconds; it would have to be millions of elements. Anyway, the relevant aspect is percentage difference, which on my setup turns out to be over 10% in favor of increment (who knows why, though :)

Comment: Its Not a Question of inc or dec, its more the compare to 0 Or n

Comment: @AlexWien How do you know that? It's both at the same time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i asume it, because inc and dec have same speed at cpu level, but compare to 0 is faster. But what the VM finally does is another question

Comment: @AlexWien I already had the discussion once about comparison to zero. It turned out that even on the original old 8086, there was no difference at all. But anyway, if you have anything in the way of proof for your thesis, please let me know.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ok, i had never measured it, and will not do in future. i just remembered Z80 and MOS 6502 assembler, ... long time ago ...

Comment: @AlexWien Ahh, the memories :) But the main point from the assembler perspective is skipping a `cmp ax, [n]` because after `dec ax` you can directly use `jnz loop`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never wonder; use Google Caliper to find out. Since there has been quite a bit of discussion around the relative weights of testing against zero vs. upper limit and incrementing vs. decrementing, here's the Cartesian product of all these cases:

```
import java.util.Random;

import com.google.caliper.Runner;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class Performance extends SimpleBenchmark {
  static final Random rnd = new Random();

  public int timeDecrementToZero(int reps) {
    int sum = rnd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (int j = Integer.MAX_VALUE; j >= 0; j--) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public int timeDecrementFromZero(int reps) {
    int sum = rnd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j > Integer.MIN_VALUE; j--) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public int timeIncrementFromZero(int reps) {
    int sum = rnd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < Integer.MAX_VALUE; j++) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public int timeIncrementToZero(int reps) {
    int sum = rnd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (int j = Integer.MIN_VALUE; j < 0; j++) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Runner.main(Performance.class, args);
  }
}
```

Results:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=DecrementToZero} 984060500.00 ns; σ=30872487.22 ns @ 10 trials
25% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=DecrementFromZero} 982646000.00 ns; σ=35524893.00 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=IncrementFromZero} 1023745500.00 ns; σ=24828496.82 ns @ 10 trials
75% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=IncrementToZero} 1081112500.00 ns; σ=20160821.13 ns @ 10 trials

        benchmark   ms linear runtime
  DecrementToZero  984 ===========================
DecrementFromZero  983 ===========================
IncrementFromZero 1024 ============================
  IncrementToZero 1081 ==============================
```

Apparently, whether the limit is zero or not has less effect than using inc vs. dec.

### Let's change it just a tiny bit...

To point out just how tenouous these differences are, here's virtually the same code, but now it uses `long`s (I include one method from the first example, to maintain scale):

```
  public int timeDecrementFromZeroInt(int reps) {
    int sum = rnd.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j > Integer.MIN_VALUE; j--) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public long timeDecrementFromZero(int reps) {
    long sum = rnd.nextLong();
    for (long i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (long j = 0; j > Integer.MIN_VALUE; j--) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public long timeIncrementFromZero(int reps) {
    long sum = rnd.nextLong();
    for (long i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (long j = 0; j < Integer.MAX_VALUE; j++) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public long timeDecrementToZero(int reps) {
    long sum = rnd.nextLong();
    for (long i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (long j = Integer.MAX_VALUE; j >= 0; j--) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  public long timeIncrementToZero(int reps) {
    long sum = rnd.nextLong();
    for (long i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
      for (long j = Integer.MIN_VALUE; j < 0; j++) sum += j;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Results:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=DecrementFromZeroInt} 978513000.00 ns; σ=14861284.82 ns @ 10 trials
20% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=DecrementFromZero} 2160652000.00 ns; σ=13825686.87 ns @ 3 trials
40% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=IncrementFromZero} 2153370000.00 ns; σ=6318160.49 ns @ 3 trials
60% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=DecrementToZero} 4379893000.00 ns; σ=8739917.79 ns @ 3 trials
80% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=IncrementToZero} 4383569000.00 ns; σ=5798095.89 ns @ 3 trials

           benchmark   ms linear runtime
DecrementFromZeroInt  979 ======
   DecrementFromZero 2161 ==============
   IncrementFromZero 2153 ==============
     DecrementToZero 4380 =============================
     IncrementToZero 4384 ==============================
```

Main conclusion: never assume anything about performance at such a low level. Write your full code and test it as a whole because there will always be something else you are not taking into account, which completely turns the tables.

Comment: Man, this is awesome. But why I can't download it? Is this the correct link to download - http://code.google.com/p/caliper/ ?

Comment: There are no artifacts to download, just check out the source code at http://code.google.com/p/caliper/source/checkout.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a significant result.  The introduction of summation in opposite directions, I would suspect, likely has a larger impact on the time taken, and since you are iterating to INTEGER.MAX_VALUE, and summing into an int, you'll be running into integer overflow as well.

Comment: The Question is Not the decrement vs increment, ist is the compare to zero. You. Oi

Comment: You can't take _everything_ out of the loop, or the JIT will eliminate the whole loop.

Comment: @femtoRgon The summation of any two ints is exactly as complex for the CPU, and a single-cycle operation in all cases. The very fact that overflow can happen is a guarantee that this is true.

Comment: I wish I could vote enough times to give you a reversal badge on this one.

Comment: This is meaningless. Try making `n` a volatile field (or doing something in the loop that prevents the compiler from recognizing that `n` is constant for the duration of the loop) and your results will be quite different.

Comment: Note: the numbers are the same within test error.

Comment: @TedHopp What do you mean by `n`? There is no variable named `n` here, and nothing is constant in the loop, except the loop bounds.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What do you mean? Sigma is 4% so the difference is 3 sigma.

Comment: My point is, when we're talking a trivial machine code advantage of a preference in iteration for comparing to 0, and that being somehow translated into a measurable difference when run in the JVM, I think it's certainly pertinent to discuss what ramifications the attempt at measureing it has, before accepting a result to mean something it doesn't. I wouldn't normally worry at any advantage between simple equalities, or whether setting the overflow flag has an impact, or the finer points of the JVM's internal interpretations impact on time for simple ops. But it's the only way to address this.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to `n` in OP's original code. You are using `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which the compiler knows perfectly well is a constant. The difference between counting up to a volatile value versus counting down from it to 0 is huge.

Comment: @TedHopp But of course, then you are stacking one volatile read against `Integer.MAX_VALUE` reads of it. We want something that pronounces increment vs. decrement as much as possible. To test your hypothesis that the compiler precomputes the outcome of the loop, the timing should not be influenced by the specific value of the loop bound. This is easily falsifiable.

Comment: @TedHopp I updated the code sample, I think this is a good response to your criticism of the first version.

Comment: You are now starting at 0 and going either up to `limit` or down to `-limit`. That's not the relevant comparison. Try comparing counting up from 0 to limit against going from limit down to 0.

Comment: @TedHopp Why? Now it clearly shows that this is about inc vs. dec and not about comparing to zero vs. nonzero. I can add two more that both compare to zero.

Comment: Why is it necessarily about inc vs. dec? OP's code is inc from 0 to `n` vs. dec from `n` to 0. I maintain that if `n` is `volatile` (or otherwise changeable), then going from `n` to 0 is much faster. It's the nature of the limit, not inc vs. dec, that's the important issue.

Comment: I see with your latest version you are using `zero` instead of `0`. That keeps avoiding the true comparison. I challenge you to test **OP's code** with different kinds of declarations for `n`.

Comment: @TedHopp What you maintain is a trivially true observation. Testing against a `volatile` limit is clearly and undisputedly slower than testing against a local var/compile-time constant. If you think this question is about that, though, I maintain you are mistaken.

Comment: @femtoRgon I've modified it to start from a random initial value for the sum. This changed the results quite a bit, bringing them closer together.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's a compelling result for comparing increment and decrement operations.  Each operation performed in those pairs is a equivalent barring the change of sign.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Having had a chance to do some testing of this myself, Using a summation function much like you have here, I've noticed result that differ from yours, interestingly.  I tested inc and dec on ranges Integer.MAX_VALUE/2 (that is, 0 to .5max, .5max to max, -.5max to 0, etc.), I no significant time differences in ints, or favoring loops exitting at 0, but a very clear difference in tests using longs, favoring decrement in both positive and negative ranges.  A marked disagreement with your results.  Seems this may indicate a significant dependance on runtime environment?

Comment: @femtoRgon Naturally, yes. The differences we are measuring amount to a single different machine instruction. It surprised me that longs are slower than ints on a 64-bit JVM. I'm studying the disassembled JIT code, maybe I find out something interesting.

Answer (score 4):

it's possible that the CPU has a faster method of comparing a number (i) against 0 vs. comparing against another arbitrary number (n).  This would theoretically make the decrement version faster.

This is purely academic though, IMHO.  They're both fundamentally "the same", so you should implement the one which is more logical and understandable to whomever maintains your code after you.

Answer (score 2):

Just write your loops the way it makes the most sense to write them. It's unlikely you're (a) doing anything so time-critical that a few extra nanoseconds for the entire duration of your program will make a difference and (b) your code is *so* optimized that the bottleneck is the increment or decrement operations in a loop.

If, after you test, profiling shows a particular loop to be a problem, then worry about optimizing that loop, focusing on the loop body instead of things like increment and decrement.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it depends on what `n` is. When counting down, the code only needs to access `n` once. When counting up, this may not be true. So, for instance, if `n` is a `volatile` field, or if something in the loop body may change the value of `n`, the value needs to be looked up each time through the loop. This will slow the loop down significantly.

With this code, counting up is several hundred times slower than counting down:

```
public class Counts {
    private static final int ITERS = 100000;
    volatile int n = 1000;

    public long countUp() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERS; ++iter) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
        return System.nanoTime() - start;
    }

    public long countDown() {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERS; ++iter) {
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
        return System.nanoTime() - start;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is any measurable diffetence, than the Variant by comparing to 0  is faster because on CPU Level a compare to 0 is faster.
However in most cases you better stay with a Good readable code

Answer (score 0):

The difference in time is insignificant in most cases compared to the amount of time necessary for someone else to understand what's going on. Just use whatever's easiest to follow. If you wanted to test it you could run something like this:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();  
long duration, endTime;  

for (int i=0;i<1000 ;i++ ) {  
        //function
   }  

endTime = System.nanoTime();  
duration = endTime - startTime;  

System.out.printf("The duration was %d.%03d microseconds%n", duration / 1000, duration % 1000);
```

for both increment and decrement.

The bigger issue is post- verses pre- increment/decrement. There's a pretty good explanation starting on the bottom of page 2 here: http://www.iar.com/Global/Resources/Developers_Toolbox/C_Cplusplus_Programming/Writing%20optimizer-friendly%20code.pdf